# Hyphens when using "something + style" to describe something?

Tags: orthography

> *He lit the fire Cherokee style.*

or:

> *He lit the fire Cherokee-style.*

I have seen both. Which is correct?

And, if it's the second option, then what about "multiple words + style"? E.g.:

> *She organized the view spiral staircase style.*

versus:

> *She organized the view spiral-staircase-style.*

(which looks very wrong)

Comment: In the absence of any other compelling factors, there is simply no need for the hyphen. *Cherokee style* as well as *spiral staircase style* are perfectly acceptable and understandable without ambiguity.

Answer (score 5):

You should use hyphens when the phrase appears as an adjectival phrase—just as you would any [compound modifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_compound#Hyphenated_compound_modifiers)—for example,

> *The Cherokee-style headdress was quite impressive.*

In your example, it appears to be an [adverbial phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_phrase), in which case, I believe hyphens are not warranted. You may add an (optional) comma to avoid confusion:

> *He lit the fire, Cherokee style.*
>
> *She organized the view, spiral-staircase style.*

In the second, sentence '*spiral-staircase*' is an adjectival phrase describing '*style*'.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:

1. The second.
2. Read on.

The first is just *that*. Not much explanation.

The second does indeed get weird with multiple words. With a compound noun like yours, you'd want

> She organized the view spiral staircase-style.

"Spiral staircase" is one noun.

Comment: This was my suspicion. The ideal answer has some references!

Comment: To me, *She organized the view spiral staircase-style* is even more confusing than the original. It seems like an inversion of *staircase-style(adj) spiral(n)*, which just doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: I agree, the hyphen belongs here: _spiral-staircase_ style

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, spiral staircase-style, but the "hyphen" should be an en dash (not an em dash). (I get these with an alt-hyphen command.)

Comment: please elaborate why

Comment: That's wrong — it should be a hyphen, not a dash. What I used in the previous sentence is an example of an em dash. An en dash should be used for ranges (like "ages 9-90"). A hyphen is what makes compound words.